# CC/BCC AmpScript not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I am trying to dynamically generate the CC/BCC fields within an email activity.

In the email I've put this:

```
%%[ 
var @ShopEmail
set @ShopEmail = 'x.x@gmail.com'
]%%
%%=v(@ShopEmail)=%%
```

In the email activity I've put this:
%%=v(@ShopEmail)=%%

The print within the email is working but the email activity BCC is not working at all.
When I type the email address there manually it works, but through AmpScript it is not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: I havent tried it yet. But thinking of dynamic subjects.. do you have that ampscript before the body part of the html?

Comment: This might not be possible at the moment. The CC/BCC fields are part of Journey Builder configuration and Ampscript is not executed in that context. In case of emails, this is not mentioned in the documentation explaining the order of operations: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/orderOfOperations.htm

Comment: @RafałWolsztyniak Would personalization strings work there?

Comment: @user3485470 Good idea with the personalization strings - they actually do work here as a dynamic source of CC email addresses. After my previous comment I found this article claiming Ampscript was working from the standard send flow (not JB), but I could not manage to get it to work for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

So, the CC and BCC sections are like **[the Sender Profile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203938/dynamic-sender-profile-not-working)** and are created/processed prior to the actual body of the email. These are run during the creation of the header of the email, so they will not contain any information that you have inside the HTML Email body due to the cascading processing of AMPScript.

If you put self contained AMPScript (or reference a self contained AMPScript code snippet block) or utilize personalization strings, you can create dynamic CC/BCC (**[ref](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_select_audience.htm&type=5)**). But you cannot use any information that requires the email content to be processed since it is below this section in the OOO.

so if in the CC field or a content block (and then reference that block in CC) you put your AMPScript:

```
%%[ 
var @ShopEmail
set @ShopEmail = 'x.x@gmail.com'
]%%
%%=v(@ShopEmail)=%%
```

Then it should work as expected.

Same if you use a personalization string by attaching a field in the sendable DE to contain the 'ShopEmail'. `%%ShopEmail%%` in the CC field should fill it in. But realize that if you do not have this field in the sendable data, it will cause the email to error, same as normal with personalization string.

Comment: So in my case this shopemail is calculated at send time depending on which store the subscriber cancelled his click & collect order. So the store managers receive a duplicate of the cancellation request. Will this work then? Because I can't see how a referenced block would be able to do these calculations. So the only way to make this personalized per subscriber context would be personalization strings?

Comment: You can do lookups based on sendable data fields still. You may just need to do those calculations inside of the block as well to get the correct info for the correct CC/BCC conditional values. It likely would require a duplication of effort (potentially increasing processing time), but is possible to be done.

Comment: Has anyone had luck with this? I have not been able to get ampscript to work. Personalization strings work, IE %%email%%, but this does not %%[Set @email ="my@email.com"]%%%%=v(@email)%%