# Is there a character limit on From Names in sender Profiles using AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have been using some AMPScript that Lookups a column in a DE to set what the FROM Name should be in my sender profile, this has been used for well over a year without any problems.

Recently we've had complaints from subscribers that the sender name contains weird code, it turns out that the AMPScript is being displayed, however truncated to the first 130 characters.

Has anyone else come across this issue? Has there been changes to the way FROM NAMEs can be set in Sender Profiles?

Comment: Take a look here, where Eliot explains how to use content block in Sender Profiles: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233323/sender-profile-ampscript

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had this problem, So I wrote AmpScript code inside the content Block and started calling the content block with "ContentBlockByID". You can also use other functions from the AmpScript documentation

[Code Snippet](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_create_code_snippet.htm&type=5)