# Dynamic sender profile not working - From address

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to set up a dynamic sender profile but something is wrong.

I've followed this solution step by step: [Sender Profile AMPscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233323/sender-profile-ampscript)

But it doesn't work. Problem seems to be the from address, since the sender profile does not appear in the preview and test drop down list any longer as soon as I set a dynamic from address. If I set it static, with a verified address, and use the dynamic block for the from name only, the sender profile appears in the dropdown list again, but the email fails to arrive.

I've created a very simple dynamic block:

```
%%[ 

var @fromName 
var @fromAddress

set @a = 1
set @b = 2

if a == 1 then
 set fromName = "From Name 1"
 set @fromAddress = "firstEmail@email.com"
else
 set fromName = "From Name 2"
 set @fromAddress = "secondEmail@email.com"

ENDIF

]%%
```

I changed the email addresses for privacy purposes, but the ones I am using are correctly verified.
And then added ampscript to my sender info fields:

```
%%[ContentBlockByKey("sender-profile")]%%%%=v(@fromName)=%%
%%[ContentBlockByKey("sender-profile")]%%%%=v(@fromAddress)=%%
```

I can't see any error in the code. Is there anything I am missing?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is an error in your If statement, it should be if @a == 1. Also in the set statments

Comment: True, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Make sure this feature is enabled in your account
Your code has syntax issues.

```
 %%[
var @fromName 
var @fromAddress

set @a = 1
set @b = 2

if @a == 1 then
 set @fromName = "From Name 1"
 set @fromAddress = "firstEmail@email.com"
else
 set @fromName = "From Name 2"
 set @fromAddress = "secondEmail@email.com"

ENDIF

]%%
%%=v(@fromAddress)=%%
```

And then used `%%=ContentBlockbyId("ContentID")=%%` in the from email under sender profile.

Comment: True, but still having the same problem.

Comment: Updated Answer above

Comment: Ok, I am seeing the sender profile in the dropdown list now, but when I send the email, it never gets delivered.  This is what is shown in the tracking: https://ibb.co/HVgFY5Q

Comment: Try to test your code snippet in an email to see whether you get an ampscript error

Comment: Code works fine, no errors. The variable is shown correctly...

Comment: I tested it and looks fine for me. May be check on the verified email address in the from management, also, would be good if you could post your code, sender profile configuration in the question above.

Comment: The email I am using is verified, I've checked already.I just read on the documentation that "enhanced sender profile" must be enabled in order to use dynamic sender profiles. Do you know how to check if this is actually enabled? Can't find much on the documentation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116091/discussion-between-swati-mishra-and-robruf).

Comment: This hasn't worked out yet unfortunately. Turns out that "enhanced sender profile" is already enabled. I really don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Hi @robruf, have you tried wrapping your ContentBlockByKey() within a TreatAsContent()? Something like this might help: 

%%=TreatAsContent(ContentBlockByKey('ContentID'))=%%

Answer (score 0):

have you tried wrapping your ContentBlockByKey() call within a TreatAsContent()? I believe something like this might help.

```
%%=TreatAsContent(ContentBlockByKey('ContentID'))=%%
```

Also, I believe that all the dynamic from email addresses you're wanting to use need to use the approved domain for your account. Judging by your code, it appears that you're trying to use the domain email.com in your dynamic from email addresses. Since email.com isn't the approved domain for your account I imagine that's why your emails are probably failing.

If you navigate to `Admin > Send Management > Sender Profiles > Default` you can look at the From Email field to see what domain is used on your account. And as long as the dynamic from emails you're trying to use share that same domain.com then it should send for you. Otherwise I believe the email fails on the backend. Well, I hope this information helps in someway. Best of luck!