# Create Dynamic Sender profile based on any filtered data extension with common logo field (sync)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, reply-mail-management

My goal is to create a Dynamic Sender profile based on any filter data extension (from sync) that would have the same "logo" field to determine the from name and from email. With this being a common field, I would like to avoid doing a data extension lookup so that it will work with future filtered data extensions.

I am also wondering if there is a way to use "Custom Reply Mail management", "Use specified information" address dynamically. I am assuming you could use a similar method as the From Email.

I haven't had much luck with finding helpful documentation. This [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233323/sender-profile-ampscript) seems to be the closest I have gotten.

I created a Content Block, HTML type with "sender-profile" as the customer key.

```
    %%[
var @fromName, @fromEmail

if AttributeValue('LogoField') == 'Logo1' then
   set @fromName = 'Name 1'
   set @fromEmail = 'user@email-1.com'
elseif AttributeValue('LogoField') == 'Logo2' then
   set @fromName = 'Name 2'
   set @fromEmail = 'user@email-2.com'
else /* fallback if neither evaluates to true */
   set @fromName = 'Name 1'
   set @fromEmail = 'user@email-1.com'
endif
]%%
```

However, when I did the below step in the "Sender Profile" it disappears from the dropdown selection upon send. The "Send Classification" says, a message in a yellow bar which says, "The sender profile originally selected has been deleted or is no longer verified for sending. Please select a different sender profile."
All email addresses have been verified in the "From Address Management".

> 2. Add AMPscript to your Sender Information fields (below code),

From Name:

```
%%[ContentBlockByKey("sender-profile")]%%%%=v(@fromName)=%%
```

From Email:

```
%%[ContentBlockByKey("sender-profile")]%%%%=v(@fromEmail)=%%
```

[The question I used this from](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233323/sender-profile-ampscript) seems to be possibly based upon triggered send as suppose to single. However I am wondering the best method to use for single send that is based off of a field, not an actual field that exists that contains the "From email" or "From Name" listed.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I apologize if my post is not in the correct format, I am trying to improve.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the content block as a Code Snippet, not as an HTML content block. There was a change a few years ago where HTML blocks are now wrapped in tables, which could cause these values to be wrapped in table tags (and produce invalid values).

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment Eliot! I noticed I was missing the space in between "%%%%" in the "From Name" and "From Email" statements from the related article. Once I corrected this it appears to work with the HTML Blocks. I will likely update those blocks to be Code Snippets though upon your recommendation.

Do you know if the Reply address can be updated in a similar fashion like the from name/address if it's a different content block called upon?

Comment: A space character is not required between the block and inline delimiter patterns. In fact, I'd recommend you don't include one, otherwise your email address and from name would be prefixed with a space character.

Comment: I found out that If there is no space between "%%%%" then the sender profile does not appear as a choice to select when sending. The emails I received did not have a space character. I appreciate your input.

Comment: That must have been a recent change as this pattern certainly used to work. Good to hear that trailing spaces are ignored though.